# How does the Trump administrations "rate of attrition" compare to past administrations?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump, statistics, political-appointments

There have been a number of high-profile firings / forced resignations / etc in recent years originating from the Trump administration. Some of these, such as John Bolton, have ended up as media headlines

How does the number of presidential appointees which have resigned (or been otherwise removed) during his administration, as well as the rate at which other government officials have left their posts at the President's request, compare to past administrations?

This question is something of a duplicate of [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/how-does-turnover-in-the-trump-administration-compare-to-previous-administration) asked in 2018; however, as that question (and answer) are two years old now, I am interested in an answer with more current information (2020).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Politifact [cited the same Brookings Institute study in 2018](https://www.politifact.com/article/2018/jul/11/look-white-house-turnover-scott-pruitt/)

> After a year and a half, 57 percent of Trump’s top White House positions changed hands. (This analysis covers 65 positions.)

> For context, after two years in office, Barack Obama’s White House had a 24 percent turnover rate, George W. Bush had 33 percent, Clinton had 38 percent, George H. W. Bush had 35 percent, and Ronald Reagan had 57 percent.

They also note this (emphasis mine)

> **Trump’s White House saw turnover in 75 percent of these positions**, which include the chief of staff, White House counsel and National Security Adviser. Obama’s White House saw turnover in 41 percent of these positions by the end of his second year. At the lower end of the spectrum, both Bushes saw 17 percent turnover, and at the other end, Clinton and Reagan saw 58 and 59 percent turnover, respectively.

The current [June 19, 2020 Brookings Institute report](https://www.brookings.edu/research/tracking-turnover-in-the-trump-administration/) says

> President Trump’s “A Team” turnover is 88% as of June 19, 2020

Obama's Year 4 turnover rate was 71%. The closest to that rate would be Reagan at 78%

Comment: What are the "these positions" in the second paragraph? Ah, the link says the 12 most important positions, the "decision makers", but doesn't list them in the article.